# cleanthesis - logo on each page after first chapter page

Tags: koma-script, alignment, tocloft, footer, cleanthesis

I currently use the cleanthesis v0.4.0 and my main issue right now is that I'm not able to place a logo on each page after the first page of the chapter. Used fancyhdr but I get always the complain that it doesn't work with "tocloft". Is there any other method?

Another point is, how am I able to reduce the distance of my text to the footer. The gap where a pagebreak is initiated is way too big.

Lastly, I don't want offset of the section number and the text below. I tried quite a few things in the cleanthesis.sty but nothing really works.

[image]

Comment: Your MWE to make our helping work easier?

Comment: `cleanthesis` uses package `scrlayer-scrpage`, so you cannot and need not use `fancyhdr`. You have to use the `scrlayer-scrpage` interface to configure page head and foot.

Answer (score 1):

Distance to a footer can be change by altering `\footskip`. You can change it either by adding a relative value to it (negative values would decrease the distance)

```
\addtolength{\footskip}{-12pt}
```

or by setting an absolute value

```
\setlength\footskip{...}
```

Also, have a look at "page layout" produced by LaTeX to see what other parameters can be changed; for instance page 7 in [fancyheader](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) contains such page. I'd also add to your preamble this snippet to see how header/footer/margin notes look like with respect to the main text

```
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
```

Since you have applied a custom layout, you probably need to consult with [cleanthesis](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleanthesis) documentation if you want to change settings of your document.

**Logo**
Below is the full example applying a logo in chapter 2 at the right-hand upper corner. The file uses the standard `report`. Make sure your LaTeX distribution is not too old (older than 2020). Otherwise, you might need to use one of the packages [eso-pic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) or even older [background](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/background).

```latex
\documentclass{report}
% \usepackage{cleanthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
%% Chapter 1 - no logo
\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext

%% Chapter 2 with a logo
\cleardoublepage
\AddToHook{shipout/background}[logo]{%
  \put(\dimexpr\pagewidth-6cm,-3cm){%
    \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=2cm]{example-image-duck}}}
\chapter{The main chapter}
\Blindtext

%% Chapter 3 - no logo
\cleardoublepage
\RemoveFromHook{shipout/background}[logo]
\chapter{Conclusion}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]